# How to get active head count from start time to end time in a day using 30 mins of time intervals

Tags: excel-2007

In Column D-Scheduled Start time, in column E-Scheduled End Time, in column F-Agent arrival time and in column N-Start time in 30 mins of Time interval and column O-END time in 30 mins of Time interval. I want count of active agents for every 30 mins in a day 24/7.
=IF(AND($N13>=$D13,$O13<=$E13),COUNT($F$5:$F$57),0) this formula executing full count
=COUNTIFS(F5:F57,">="&N14,F5:F57,"<"&O14) this is showing zero.
Please suggest.

I tried two different formulas did not work.
Expected Result is: Active agents in this hour/30 minutes. (Randam numbers as example).
7:00 am - 5 agents
8:00 am - 9 agents
9:00 am - 25 agents
Again when agents logged out count reduces
4:00 pm - 20 agents
5:00 pm - 11 agents
6:00 pm - agents if any OT.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.